# Check whether subset of R dataframe/data.table rows are all zero, or contain several ones

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following `data.table` (though I'm happy to use an R dataframe as well):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread("filename.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE)

print(dt)
>>>   grouping    labels    count    variety
1        item1    0         0        1   
2        item2    1         0        0       
3        item3    0         0        1          
4        item4    1         0        0       
5        item5    0         0        1       
6        item6    0         1        0       
7        ...               ...         ....
```

The three columns `labels`, `count`, and `variety` are binary columns labeling the category of the item. Each item only has a unique category, i.e. each row should contain two zeros and only one 1.

How could I check this? I suspect there's an error in this data.table, and I would like to check whether rows contain all zeros.

I'm able to subset only on those columns:

```
dt = dt[, c(2:4)]
```

but then I'm stuck. I would use a for loop to evaluate whether each of the items by row are == 0, but that's not a very "R" solution.

Comment: `which(rowSums(dt[,c(2:4)]) != 1)` should give you the rows with problems.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! This shows if the rows are all zero. What if there are 2-3 ones per row?

Comment: (I edited the comment a few seconds after posting it. The edited version checks for rows that are not 1, so sums of 0, 2, or 3 should all trigger as wrong. If you run the `!= 1` version and see no rows, that suggests you are fine. Note: this does not check for `NA`, in case that's a concern/risk.)

Comment: Alternately, reshape `m = melt(dt, id="grouping")`, check `m[, if (sum(value) != 1L) .SD, by=grouping]`, then filter once it's confirmed `dt_new = m[ value == 1L, !"value" ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using data.table:

```
library(data.table)
dt[, error := rowSums(.SD) !=1, .SDcols = 2:4, by=grouping]

print(dt)

grouping labels count variety error
1:    item1      0     0       1 FALSE
2:    item2      1     0       0 FALSE
3:    item3      0     0       1 FALSE
4:    item4      1     0       0 FALSE
5:    item5      0     1       1  TRUE
6:    item6      0     1       0 FALSE
```

See 5th case where item5 has value 1 for two columns and is marked with error == TRUE